Where in GCP Logs Explorer I can find Standard App Engine's firewall logs
I'm currently managing firewall rules within GCP App Engine, and I'm seeking guidance on how to access the corresponding App Engine's firewall logs in Log Explorer. I'm encountering difficulties in identifying the specific log names associated with these rules. Could someone provide insights or steps on how to locate and view these firewall logs effectively within the Log Explorer interface? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Despite attempting to filter the log name to "firewall," I haven't had any success. Additionally, within the App Engine section, I only see request log names. I suspect that firewall logs might be listed elsewhere.

Have you enabled the logging for the app engine fw rule?
Based on this doc, it seems that you have to specify it
gcloud compute firewall-rules create MY-RULE --enable-logging
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create#--[no-]enable-logging

@MrThompson Thank you for your comment. The document that you are referring to is for compute. I'm using app engine and I do not see any enablement option in the relevant documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/firewall-rules
In-fact I am using the panel. Let me go deeper in the CLI.

I see the --log-http flag for both compute and app engine. Do you know if this is related? i don't think so. It's general flag for logging server request (not firewall)
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--log-http

I test it. It didn't work. I created a firewall rule with --log-http flag to Deny my own IP. The rule worked but I do not see any log.

if you check this documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/creating-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules you will see the command to create the app engine firewall rules.
Then if you go for the flags for such command you will see that there is a --enable-logging that I'm referring to. Not the --log-http.

This is for the "flexible" App Engine. I am using the "Standard" App engine. They are different. It seems there is no logging for the Standard one!

Apologize you're correct about that. Nevertheless reviewing the standard app engine documentation I can find the same information
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/creating-firewalls

@MrThompson Thank you for the link. I see no information about logs on the page. Did I miss something?

the link should direct you straight to to part where it mentions how to create the firewall rules. Nevertheless
This is the example of the command
gcloud app firewall-rules create PRIORITY --action ALLOW_OR_DENY --source-range IP_RANGE --description DESCRIPTION
And if you look for the flags for that command here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create#--[no-]enable-logging you should see the flag that I am mentioning
gcloud compute firewall-rules create MY-RULE --enable-logging

@MrThompson Nope. The --enable-logging flag that you are referring to is for the "compute" service and is not implemented for Standard App Engine". If you try the create command with this flag you get the following error: ERROR: (gcloud.app.firewall-rules.create) unrecognized arguments: --enable-logging

I submitted a Feature Request to Google to add it. Please go and vote for it to be prioritized and added: issuetracker.google.com/issues/339654375 

You're right. Just reviewed and I was sharing the wrong gcloud docs, sorry about that. Giving a thumbs up to your feature request

I assume you're using Google App Engine Standard. If so, then I don't believe what you're tying to do is possible.
According to the documentation for Firewall Rules Logging

Firewall Rules Logging logs traffic to and from Compute Engine virtual machine (VM) instances. This includes Google Cloud products built on Compute Engine VMs, such as Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters and App Engine flexible environment instances.


Then it will be a feature request I guess :) (I mentioned in the title that I am on the Standard App Engine)
BTW, they have firewall rules on Standard App Engine. Do you know why they do not have logging for the standard version?

@AminGheibi: Yes, I know that Firewall rules exist on GAE Standard (we have an Analytics App for GAE standard which automatically creates firewall rules when it identifies spam/bot visitor; while building it, we had the same question as you & couldn't find the logs for the firewall rules; we found the documentation for Firewall Rules logging; it looks like things haven't changed).

I submitted a Feature Request to Google to add it. Please go and vote for it to be prioritized and added:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/339654375
